# Citrix XenApp application does not have keyboard focus when launched

Tags: terminal-server, citrix, xenapp

On new or existing Citrix XenApp 4.5 servers, I am having problems streaming the Allscripts Pro EHR application via the XenApp web interface.

When users launch the application via the Citrix XenApp web interface, the application does not have focus, preventing users from typing in their username and password. If they use their mouse to select either the username or password fields, they still cannot enter any text.

However, if they do any of the following actions, they can then enter in their username and password and the application runs without problems:

1. Click on the Login button with empty
   fields. Logon fails but they can
   then enter their credentials.
2. Minimize the login window and then maximize it. They can then gain
   keyboard focus to enter their
   credentials.

What might be preventing this particular application from having focus when it launches?

Comment: More detail. I created a VMware ThinApp of the application in question. The ThinApp version launches with focus locally and via RDP. But when I attempt to stream the ThinApp via Citrix XenApp (ICA), the login fields for the application lack focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: launch the app seamlessly via RDP instead of Citrix.

1. Launch `mstsc`
2. Go to `Options` and browse to the `Programs` tab
3. Check the `Start the following program on connection` checkbox and enter the full path and working directory of the application or script you are launching
4. Click `Connect` and login.

Observer the behavior of the application.  If you see the same behavior, it is almost 100% certain that the problem is in the application, and 100% certain that it is not Citrix-related.

I have seen other applications behave this way when no other windows are present in the session.  If another window is open in the session when the application launches, the behavior doesn't present.

Comment: Thank you J Rightly for this suggestion, as I hadn't considered it. Unfortunately, the application launches just fine (with focus) via this RDP method. It's a VMware ThinApp of the application. The ThinApp launches fine by itself or via RDP. But when I try to publish the ThinApp via Citrix XenApp (ICA), the login screen lacks focus. If I discover a solution, I'll be sure to share.

Comment: You may want to try turning off seamless flags http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101644